# How to clear previous activities on a button click?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have found clearing all previous activities in android by some using intent flags, but I want to clear previous activities when user clicks on a button. Anyone help me, Thank you!, I have seen other stack over flow questions, no solution worked for me

Comment: Why I got negative mark?

Comment: whether this is the sequence you want  A->B->C button click close C, B and show A    correct.. ??

Comment: No, in a sequence A->B->C, on button click remain stay in C, but kill A,B @ Ragu

Comment: do you want the state of the last activity to be saved. ?

Comment: Saving the instance cannot be done, but the clearing all the previous activitites is possible.

Comment: atleast tell me that solution, But user should not feel that activity is closed

Comment: does it works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing all the running activities can be done using the following lines of code.

**For example, there are many screen running and when user clicks on logout on any of the page, should close all the activities and get the user back to the login screen. So here when you press back you will exit the app.**

> LoginActivity -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 - > Click
>   Logout --> LoginActivity [ All the in between activities are closed ]

```
    Intent next = new Intent(AnyActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    // will close all the running activiities
    next.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(next);
    finish();
```

Best Luck.!

Comment: I have tried your solution, but unfortunately previous 3 activities didn't closed.

Comment: can you please share your snippet that you have tried !!

Comment: I did the same, started Activity1, then started Activity2 and activity3. After I wanted to start activity4, and call

`Intent startVodActivity = new Intent(PopUpActivity.this,VodActivity.class);
        
        startVodActivity.putExtra("URL",mUrl);
        startVodActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startVodActivity);
        finish();`
And I was still able to hear sound from player that was started in activity1

Comment: you mean are you running any media in the activity 1 ? You can confirm by clicking back in newly created activity to confirm all other activities were finished..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this flag to clear Activity top stack

```
Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_click);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent  = getIntent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one of these way:

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class);
           MainActivity.this.finish(); //Use your current activity
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Or in Manifest file use **`android:noHistory="true"`**

```
<activity android:name=".YourNewActivity"
   android:noHistory="true"/>
```

Comment: I don't want move to another activity, I still want to stay in that activity